# How to show the Favicon of a Web Site in a PictureBox specifying the Site's URL

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019, favicon

I'm creating a bookmarks manager, where a user can add bookmarks to sites by specifying their URL.
I want to get the image the shows up on the title bar when the site is opened,  like the Google icon when `www.google.com` is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you're referring to is the web site's [Favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) (`favicon.ico`).
Most web sites have this resource exposed directly (in the site's root). It can be accessed and downloaded with a direct request:

Let's make a Directory to store these icons and ask directly a site for its `Favicon`:

```
Dim faviconsPath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Favicons")
If Not Directory.Exists(faviconsPath) Then Directory.CreateDirectory(faviconsPath)

Dim client = New WebClient()
Dim webSiteDomain = "google.com"

client.DownloadFile("http://www.google.com/favicon.ico", Path.Combine(faviconsPath, webSiteDomain & ".ico"))
PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Path.Combine(faviconsPath, webSiteDomain & ".ico"))
```

You can also use a Google's dedicated service (`http://www.google.com/s2/favicons`) and ask for the Favicon, specifying a web site's domain. Note that it will actually give you back a `PNG` image:
(using the same storage path previously defined)

```
Dim client = New WebClient()
Dim webSiteDomain = "stackoverflow.com"
Dim googleService = New Uri("http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=" & webSiteDomain)
client.DownloadFile(googleService, Path.Combine(faviconsPath, webSiteDomain & ".ico"))

PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Path.Combine(faviconsPath, webSiteDomain & ".ico"))
```

Use an interpolated string if available. e.g., :

```
PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Path.Combine(faviconsPath, $"{webSiteDomain}.ico"))
```

Comment: I'll check and tell. Thanks!

Comment: "WebClient - is not defined" ?? Why?

Comment: Did you notice this one year later :)? If WebClient is *not defined* than you didn't add `Imports System.Net`. Is this a WinForms or WPF or (other) Project?

Comment: This is a winforms project.

Comment: ...and this code is meant for a WinForms Project, that's why there's a PictureBox control. WebClient has nothing to do with WinForms specifically, it can be used anywhere.

Comment: What error? If *WebClient is not defined*, as already mentioned, you haven't added a reference to `System.Net` and/or you don't have `Imports System.Net` on top of your class. You know that you can press `ALT+ENTER` on a missing reference to make Intellisense propose the correct Assembly and Imports statements for you, right? If this is not the issue, then post the **exact** exception you get.